# Teechart: Labels and grid dissapear on axis after adding custom label

Tags: android, teechart

I need to add custom label on vertical axis in TeeChart.
For this reason I use the following code:

```
OHLC series = ...;

[..]

AxisLabelsItems labelItems = rightAxis.getLabels().getItems();
double closeValue = series.getCloseValues().getLast();
closeLabel = labelItems.add(closeValue);
```

After adding label using the code similar to provided, all the labels and lines on the right axis has dissapeared.

How is it possible to save existing labels and gridlines while adding custom label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How is it possible to save existing labels and gridlines while adding custom label?

It's not possible. When using custom labels, default automatic labels are overriden. You should add those labels you want to keep as custom labels as well.

Comment: Probably it's possible to associate the second vertical axis with my series. Then on the first axis to add my custom label and make the second axis to display automatic values. Is such workaround seems possible?

Comment: @Dennis yes, I think that would work. Moreover, you can set the OtherSide property of the other default axis to true so both axes overlap as if there was one axis only.